# Insert id (autogenerated, only column)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

How should my SQL-Statement (MS-SQL) look like if I wan't to insert a row into a table, which contains only one column with the autogenerated id?

Following two queries won't work:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (MyTableId) VALUES (Null)
-- or simply
INSERT INTO MyTable
```

Thx for any tipps.
sl3dg3

Comment: Why would you want a table with one column and that one column marked as Identity column?

Comment: More on @Cybermate comments, why you want to insert to it ;)

Comment: @Cybernate - That's easy - for compatibility/portability with a db running on Oracle, which does not have identity columns (it uses sequences instead). A table like this can be used to emulate an Oracle sequence. You'll still have to tweak your query a bit per platform, but this at least (along with a few other steps) allows your table definitions to be the same.

Comment: @Cybernate That's a table needed for language-dependencies... in fact, yes, this occurs.

Comment: @Joel: "emulate an Oracle sequence".. Can you please explain?

Comment: To create a unqiue key, against which to establish foreign key constraints, for an entity that has all of it's properties in other tables?  I've seen plenty of schema that have "floating id's", id's that have data associated to them, but never exist as a PK anywhere.  I usually would have prefered the schema to have a table like this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`INSERT INTO MyTable (MyTableId) VALUES (Null)` implicitly tries to insert a null into the identity column, so that won't work as identity columns may never be nullable and without a SET option you cannot insert an arbitrary value anyway, instead you can use:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable DEFAULT VALUES
```

Answer (score 1):

For completeness' sake, the SQL standard and most databases support the `DEFAULT VALUES` clause for this:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable DEFAULT VALUES;
```

This is supported in

- CUBRID
- Firebird
- H2
- HSQLDB
- Ingres
- PostgreSQL
- SQLite
- SQL Server (your database)
- Sybase SQL Anywhere

If the above is not supported, you can still write this statement as a workaround:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (MyTableId)  VALUES (DEFAULT);
```

This will then also work with:

- Access
- DB2
- MariaDB
- MySQL
- Oracle

For more details, see this blog post here:

http://blog.jooq.org/2014/01/08/lesser-known-sql-features-default-values/