# Create row in table with only auto generated fields - SQL

Tags: sql, db2

I've got the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE "MIGRATION"."VERSION"
(
ID BIGINT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
VERSION_DATE timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
)
```

I would like to insert a "new row" in that table but since everything is autogenerated, how could I do this?

```
INSERT INTO "MIGRATION"."VERSION" VALUES();
```

isn't working. This has to be done and can't be changed.

Comment: With this kind of question, it always helps indicating what database you're using.

Comment: It's a DB2 database. But your answer covers everything ^^

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The SQL standard and most databases support the `DEFAULT VALUES` clause for this:

```
INSERT INTO "MIGRATION"."VERSION" DEFAULT VALUES;
```

This is supported in

- CUBRID
- Firebird
- H2
- HSQLDB
- Ingres
- PostgreSQL
- SQLite
- SQL Server
- Sybase SQL Anywhere

If the above is not supported, you can still write this statement as a workaround. In fact, the first is specified by the SQL standard to be equivalent to the second:

```
INSERT INTO "MIGRATION"."VERSION" (ID, VERSION_DATE) VALUES (DEFAULT, DEFAULT);
```

This will then also work with:

- Access
- DB2
- MariaDB
- MySQL
- Oracle

For more details, see this blog post here:

http://blog.jooq.org/2014/01/08/lesser-known-sql-features-default-values/

Comment: Thanks for the DB2 explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use:

```
INSERT INTO "MIGRATION"."VERSION" DEFAULT VALUES
```

[reference Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5651171/insert-id-autogenerated-only-column)